# Generic type with any property of certain type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, index-signature

Hi everyone!

```js
interface Thing {
  name: string;
}

interface ThingMap {
  [thingName: string]: Thing;
}

interface ThingMapClassA {
  first: { name: 'first thing name' };
  second: { name: 'second thing name' };
  third: { name: 'third thing name' };
}

interface ThingMapClassB {
  first: { name: 'first thing name' };
  second: { name: 'second thing name' };
  third: { name: 'third thing name' };
}

class Handler<T extends ThingMap> {}

const handler = new Handler<ThingMapClassA>();
```

I world like `Handler` to accept any class with properties (ideally at least one) of type `Thing`. But `ThingMapClassA` is not recognised. It leads to an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're doing that thing again where you don't initialize your required class properties, causing [errors unrelated to your question](https://tsplay.dev/NVYZvw).  Could you please use interfaces or initialize your properties?  I'm sure neither of us wants to spend time discussing things that you're not asking about.

Comment: Class instances and interfaces are not given implicit index signatures, as described in [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).  Unless you want to require index signatures, you can make your constraint recursive as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoYG9N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this addresses my question. Thank you! 

Comment: Is there a way to nest it even further? Like having a Thing to have eny property of a Subthing interface?

Comment: Is that a followup question? Comments aren't an appropriate place for those, unfortunately.  You should create a new post (after searching for existing relevant questions and answers) if you need to, and include a [mre] there that demonstrates your issue (I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "nesting further"... and again, this is not the place for that discussion)

Comment: like this:

```typescript
interface Thing {
  name: string;
}

interface ThingMapClassA {
  first: { name: { name: 'first thing name' } };
}

class Handler<T extends Record<keyof T, Record<keyof T, Thing>>> {}

const handler = new Handler<ThingMapClassA>();
```

Comment:  I'm sorry, but this is not the right place for that. Please re-read my previous comment carefully.

Comment: I'm sorry to couse any trouble.  I will rewrite a new Post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type

```
interface ThingMap {
  [thingName: string]: Thing;
}
```

has a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), meaning that if an object of that type has a property whose key is a `string`, the value of that property will be a `Thing`.

If you have an anonymous object type, such as the type inferred from an object literal, and try to assign it to a type with an index signature, the compiler will helpfully give it an [implicit index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures):

```
const goodVal: ThingMap = { a: { name: "b" } }; // okay

const badVal: ThingMap = { a: "oops" }; // error
// ----------------------> ~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Thing'.
// The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

But implicit index signatures are *not* given to values of [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) or [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) instance types.  This is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).  Observe:

```
interface Iface {
  a: Thing;
}
const iface: Iface = { a: { name: "b" } };
const alsoBad: ThingMap = iface; // error!
// Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Test'.

class Cls {
  a = { name: "abc" }
}
const cls: Cls = new Cls();
const alsoAlsoBad: ThingMap = cls; // error!
// Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Cls'.
```

And that's the problem you're running into. `ThingMapClassA` and `ThingMapClassB` are not assignable to `ThingMap`, even though an anonymous object literal type equivalent to either one would be.  So you'll need to change what you're doing.

---

The easiest approach here is to change your [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be recursive.  You don't need `T` to have a string index signature; you just want to know that its properties are assignable to `Thing`.  That can be expressed as

```
class Handler<T extends Record<keyof T, Thing>> { }
```

using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type). `Record<keyof T, Thing>` means "an object with the same keys as `T`, whose properties are of type `Thing`".  So if `T extends Record<keyof T, Thing>`, then we know that every property of `T` is of type `String`.

So that gives us

```
const handler = new Handler<ThingMapClassA>(); // okay
```

and

```
const badHandler = new Handler<{ a: Thing, b: string }>(); // error!
// --------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Types of property 'b' are incompatible.
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Thing'
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8CwAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFNgNxEC+RRoksiKG2AWTgAHPERIBtMJhBYAchWp0G2ALo1+sloXaEEAexD1kWffoAmANTgAbDTKxDRAXjzI4NXKUU0ARACNfZFZgpmQAenDkfQBrOABPIgMjMGR-OCtbe0ERZFcvD2RfM2FaINYwyORoKH0oIiqAWmaW1rb2xoA+ZAA-BqjUeOEUAHJ6RlkR5GBaUn1UuFpaYCwyfxsUMH1kMCHRzSwRgDp+tHQUCAAPYYRIcx295ANKWZha8h3MWdBzK7oVshgACuUAgJ0InHA0HgSGQAEkYSgCMR3NktGwkoZjMBETQEbw8m5Cl4yJQ-IFgqFMSl3DZaPoAEIZNGOXKuHG8SpRGp1ACEpzhIF+l3+qzgwNByBgdQew2QYxUk2ms3IM2WsmmIFl+wg9GOHD0NkWswAwnSxCi4ISST4inB-Ahyhi9FjUgg6TQzbNXCAIAB3ZBegAUAEptMljLZ6QBBOmM5lnHIuJ50rnVKC1KD8whVQXC0WAkEoaVQbXy8bYKYzZCqpbYTVlkZe-UQ1tcaEEg5OM3G6MWkgwYBQeiebxk+WD4epaT10kQKYVcR0CDJcyjuc0MYrwz3GcaucL7QkGdQNduDfyk+7hxj+dUnQG9s8WFdkQ9pYM-tSocj8+2kaTsYe44Ae94kLQ25Cuu-4Qaunyzooh5Lle0HjiMV7wfuiH3roSRGksyAABJwEKGxQAAPKg1SXJAQqzAAStup7kTEEDxPoMBoAANImsidN0Xi4S6NLoCR5hkYSvoBsRpHQJRDjdvhtDRp0obaNSxjpOYMnidAkn+kRYlkeRBQsjx-g0BWGqsKpYYRNyGZ8qcHQua5zTdD0nled5Pm+Z5pyDMMswccgwi1MMUC7PK-hTHAkqgM8wjisA6xggFjwKhMhzKnMCx1mKqU7NsuxyiMBwjEAA)