# Generic type with any property of any property of certain type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Hi everyone. :)

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906108/generic-type-with-any-property-of-certain-type-in-typescript) a have the following code:

```js
interface SubThing {
  name: string;
}

interface Thing {
  subThing: SubThing; // or any other property of type SubThing like in UpperThing
}

interface UpperThing {
  thing: Thing
}

interface ThingMapA {
  map: { thing: { subThing: { name : 'subThing name' } } };
}
interface ThingMapB {
  map: { thing: { otherThing: { name : 'subThing name' } } };
}

class Handler<T extends Record<keyof T, Record<keyof T, Thing>>> {}

const handler = new Handler<ThingMapA>(); // error
const handler = new Handler<ThingMapB>(); // error
```

I world like `Handler` to accept any class with properties (ideally at least one) of type `UpperThing` which has any property (ideally at least one) of type `Thing`. But `ThingMap` is not recognised. It leads to an error. Any suggestions?

---

This is another example based on the [approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGAVAFqAc2QG8BYAKGWRDgFsIAuZAZzCkIG4KBfCi0SLEQo8hEhSrMsokASYYc+WV3K9y-cNHhJkAVQAO+6DKJlKyMErnITPPuQFbhNqwFk4+8edoemxC1Z+LNKBJNR0jMgA5FKKYjT0UcjcyckqahQIADZwzMzIABJwIAAmWdAAPNjIEAAekKX5-gDaANLIoMgA1hAAngD2MDYAukHNAAodIN19gzZtw6MuYincAHxhGeQI-SCsyLjFZdDIALzUEADuhUflUFVuHmsAFACUHMgA9J-I-V1wvQoQA) of @jcalz

```js
interface SubThing {
  name: string;
}

interface Thing {
  subThing: SubThing;
}

interface UpperThing {
  thing: Thing
}

interface ThingMapA {
  map: { thing: { subThing: { name: 'subThing name' } } };
}

interface ThingMapB {
  map: { otherThing: { subThing: { name: 'subThing name' } } };
}

interface ThingMapC {
  map: { thing: { otherSubThing: { name: 'subThing name' } } };
}

interface ThingMapD {
  map: { otherThing: { otherSubThing: { name: 'subThing name' } } };
}

class Handler<T extends { [K in keyof T]: { [P in keyof T[K]]: Thing } }> { }

const handlerA = new Handler<ThingMapA>(); // okay
const handlerB = new Handler<ThingMapB>(); // okay
const handlerC = new Handler<ThingMapC>(); // error
const handlerD = new Handler<ThingMapD>(); // error
```

Comment: Is this really a [mre]?  Where is the `name` property mentioned anywhere in `ThingMap`?  My guess is that you're looking for [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbv04m) but without an example that makes sense I can't be sure.

Comment: It was not. Sorry for that.  I corrected it. Your approach is my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. Unfortunalty this does not quite do the job. I would like to change `subThing` to `otherThing` in `ThingMap` without having the need to change it in `Thing`. The name of this properties should be generic as well. Sorry again and thanks for your time!

Comment: I don’t think I understand. Please [edit] the question to show enough examples to cover the cases you care about.

Comment: I edited my example and added another one based on your approach.

Comment: Like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wXvKVm) then? Please test to make sure it meets your needs and let me know.

Comment: This work. I see a pattern there. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the type `T` to be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that every sub-sub-property is of type `SubThing`, then you will need to write a recursive constraint involving the appropriate depth of nested [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
class Handler<T extends {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [P in keyof T[K]]: {
      [Q in keyof T[K][P]]: SubThing
    }
  }
}> { }
```

Let's test it out:

```
const handlerA = new Handler<ThingMapA>(); // okay
const handlerB = new Handler<ThingMapB>(); // okay
const handlerC = new Handler<ThingMapC>(); // okay
const handlerD = new Handler<ThingMapD>(); // okay

const badhandler = new Handler<{
  a: { b: { c: { name: "" } } },
  d: { e: { f: { name: 123 } } } // error!
}>
//   The types of 'd.e.f.name' are incompatible between these types.
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGAVAFqAc2QG8BYAKGWRDgFsIAuZAZzCkIG4KBfCi0SLEQo8hALJwADgEESFKrSlNiyMPhAFlLLKI1aa9JgHJmO9UQMQjybjZtdyvcv3DR4SZLoITJAITmUyIqSWgD2atBeWqY45vp0jMgmZoTUCda2mQ5OLoLuIuY+AMIBCkokqnEV4bjQGLGE8YZJMV5p9Bl23Nl85AJuwp6FUgAipUHlKjWRVVMRUPVRFZbGrebtVl32PL0IADZwzMzIABJwIAAme9AAPNjIEAAekJfHZIEA2gDSyKDIANYQACeoRgngAusp5FRkB8AAq-EAA4GgzzfcGQ8Yw2EARURyJBYOw6PhGKYi3M0KoTmpPAAfBUcuQEKEQKxkLhzldoLIALzUCAAd1OXOuUDuwxkdIAFABKDjIAD0iuQoX+cCBFBZbLAHNF0H8-JAQpFlzFEvEUl8MvlSpVao1WtZ7M5ZugJSNJrObvFXmKNoVytV6s1zOdutd3KgY09wu9UYtGh8IwDduDjucYZ1yEwcAukbFyFjpoT7yocC0mC0CCaiQARHWttwADTQi5aRIqGC1pgARgATABmJtp6BQUJQACE9IoQaoeBQYCBkggx1RRguADoIJuYJvLNY4FAUKAWbRJHAwMBMNccxAwIKIBAkRFmIvl6vN0A)