# Generic type with suggested functions in any property interface in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, return-type

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75906900/21520353) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75932436/21520353).

```js
// return type
interface DataA {
  value: number;
}

// return type
interface DataB {
  text: string;
}

// return type
interface DataC {
  has: boolean;
}

// correct "resolver" has at least one function with a return type
interface ResolverA {
  // 'callA' should be suggested because it is a function with a return type
  // payload is DataA
  callA(...args: any): DataA;
  // 'callB' should be suggested because it is a function with a return type
  // payload is DataB
  callB(): DataB;
}

// correct "resolver" has at least one function with a return type
interface ResolverB {
  // 'value' should not be suggested because it is a number
  value: number;

  // 'resolve' should be suggested because it is a function with a return type
  // payload is DataB
  resolve(): DataC;
}

// incorrect "resolver" has at least one function with a return typpe
interface ResolverC {
  // 'text' should not be suggested because it is a number
  text: string;
}

// should be ok because two properties have a correct "resolver" type
interface ResolversShouldWork {
  // 'has' should not be suggested because it is a number
  has: boolean;
  // 'resolverA' should be suggested because ResolverA has functions with an return type.
  resolverA: ResolverA;
  // 'resolverB' should be suggested because ResolverB has functions with an return type.
  resolverB: ResolverB;
  // 'resolverC' should not be suggested because Resolver C has no function with an return type.
  resolverC: ResolverC;
}

// should be error because no property has a correct "resolver" type
interface ResolversShouldntWorkA {
  // 'item' should not be suggested because it is a number
  item: object;
}

// should be error because no property has a correct "resolver" type
interface ResolversShouldntWorkB {
  // 'resolverC' should not be suggested because Resolver C has no function with an return type.
  resolverC: ResolverC;
}

type PickByValue<T, V> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: T[K] };
type HasProp<T, D = never> = T extends (keyof T extends never ? never : unknown)
  ? T
  : D;

type AcceptableHandler<T> = HasProp<
  PickByValue<T, (...args: any) => any>,
  { needsAtLeastOneMethod(): any }
>;

class Handler<
  TResolvers extends {
    [TResolver in keyof TResolvers]: AcceptableHandler<TResolver>;
  },
> {
  public send<
    TResolver extends Extract<keyof TResolvers, string>,
    TMethod extends Extract<keyof TResolvers[TResolver], string>,
    TPayload extends TResolvers[TResolver][TMethod] extends (
      ...args: any
    ) => infer R
      ? R
      : never,
  >(resolver: TResolver, method: TMethod, payload: TPayload) {
    //
  }
}

const handlerA = new Handler<ResolversShouldWork>(); // should be ok
const handlerB = new Handler<ResolversShouldntWorkA>(); // should be error
const handlerC = new Handler<ResolversShouldntWorkB>(); // should be error

handlerA.send('has', null, null); // 'has' should be error
handlerA.send('resolverA', 'callA', { value: 5 }); // should be ok, payload should be 'DataA'
handlerA.send('resolverA', 'callB', { text: 'hi' }); // should be ok, payload should be 'DataB'
handlerA.send('resolverB', 'resolve', { has: true }); // should be ok, payload should be 'DataC'
handlerA.send('resolverB', 'value', null); // 'value' should be error
handlerA.send('resolverC', null, null); // 'resolverC' should be error
```

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECcFMBcFdwHamgTwA6QLACgCWDpJwAzAQwGNJQARU6UgQVAG8dRQA3UgG1kgC5QCWAFsARkQDcOAL44cICDHhJUGHPkIkKVWvQBCLNskgAPaIIDO0cPgDm07HOwKwUOImToseAkTKUNHSkAMJG2OwAFqSWgmIA9vHckKQIjs6uoOTx4FDk0KAARFCWSRxEhaDRlqB0oMkxBfEIVMSwCPm4zaAA7rjQkbVKHqreGn7agQBKkKXc5eBMrBGgigDk5DzcDGuglpHxsNwAJqASe7B2drOEpxKbsJZU-aC4NaSgbR3QXUh9A0N3CovOoVoo0KQUNx4qRTm8gvQGMZNtxtgAKAB0WNI4DssVqCBQAEpBHpGI52OsUdx9Lt9ocTmcqJZLtdrJA7pAHk9XgV4R8vp1uv9Bh8gZ41D5KWAIVCYXCamT9Mitvo0SSEaR9Ol5NhFNlclyCsVZmUKlUYrUCg1rKBmq12kK-v1RcNgZLxloAlQZnMFoZltLQGsuLxIHSDkdTgh4gVziyrjcOUzuc8+e8hKIJOBjKG+IJhOIpLqg2sSmaIwzORdE+zOanea8M4KfsKXYDlBKxmCZZDobCm5rlSty-NIOrScEQjqXHqwPgDXljaOFpVqlb6ilbfbPo7W86AWLO6M0KDNP4dKBfWbwGFA6swGtCOZK1GhLGmTW2bcU6RHmnBw+Qts2MZ8LD2Gx7BnTJ6Tfc54gAa1-f9kB6eJQDQcB4gwcAflmC1yiGRcjSKFdzQ9XwvUva8x3ASwAGVIxOAB1HIkPvdZqlfRkYzjZlWSTes-x5F5+UzIscxWao4kSBo0mMdYyMWbjqwTb9k3uYSfVNWimHXFtfhqEUCTdLsMAxYwlIYQQaIWBgKQfYMlNpPYmNUgS62QnlbKIQx9L3QzenbVJTJPSALJHHT-RsqLfIcxTYtvFT3z4r9BK87S-SIUAwnXGNd2+X4gsPJBxTCiL2CUkIYqy29oLnVyq0-IgsPADL3wwrCcNQC0M2I-JSMSyoKPPSZMpvBi3IIVjwAQpYFMffpIBEZLeM-NT0s0lDRIzYCiGMJaREEeIxAAKyNerFFgxlzhanJ2vyzDsKIHr1w+frlyGkEfFG70r0Syaq2mtiAwWpzEpCVaP3jDyfy27zEpy3qOoMtsStC76KqUWrqv+nH6slUAAAVcHIBD9BQAA1Hg+AAHgAFQAGlASmAD5QAAXhYUAAG0AGlXiQBDIBQeJiFAenahqen+YAXVAMxCAQY4akp0AAH5QAFgtIAWWXBBlvn5ZkRxCYACRiImuoZ5nqE5oRdaIdmuclxXIGVmo0WF0Xxdd8x3ZVh2Fg1oPssEdoEJjHoECJYxNfp4xSUcHBCYYchKDQegxGSC3leScAGed0ALcsK3sNp4wSbJinqbDG3QExbFcXxVJiU59nW9ZxnjGYB2OUsBhoAAGS3aAAHkWgAWRgA5jgnAkUFAZxWeT7ByG4GIalz4584rlZ6Z8uiFf9j3wnYdgeYPxH8FAb2xYlw-LH10A04zrOc9SHeiAZw+V+MGRu7YHZveNAsBs6kz2AHPe58H6IzdqfAAouYcAFBoC0zvr7R+zNrC2AQHYLuxh2D02ngMeIpx4GByQTYVB6CRb3yvrVSwl9D6y2wZBPBBCVhEKJn2eUx8laBwYRNZhiVZaXxIbPeWFDPaEPPliDEOI8SCFbrIok7dBbEGylMWR7BNbaK4efHWCxAHsFZmiJSBtD7MxEDPMhBsJFkOZrKfsxwDY8LlLCNR95pT-1kLqbICBbTRDzkQJgXMWg9GLp-Xej9GJVhmghMxRJJCOWutWRCOAAlBOib5e2ESokhILrEqa0AEkMCSSkq6blmq5ByJk5o2TClhHCZASJ28YkAziVGYGs19AVNSdU26tTJI4GCV-RYGInjKzRGsLizNhConmUcbgyTHKzJiMlIZrVRk5ImVMueZZEo7GZhsLYxzuZ5gEKAAArEvVZVSmrwQQk43hA40mfjWGSHYOzCkMEmQHGZVk1gnOpLSZmvcwKCFmbgXYMh7lgHeU8l5HjTiIqoJ84ItIfnjL+fswFiUwXgyysC7m0lkDgD4HcypCLBlUEQsilxjU4LorJJDbF+dcUAsObVQlIYabhiWaieFwZLmbKoHdSSYyOX-Omdym8kNBXcEVcKuVtFIZMpuuK4ZOAgA).

I would like `Handler` to only accept interfaces with properties of a type having functions with a return type for a payload.
It doesn't matter if the functions have parameters or not.
So if you create a new interface having properties with types having at least one function with a return type it should work as a generic parameter for `Handler` as well.

There are some suggestions that should be autocompleted, some not.
The first parameter of `handlerA`'s function `send` should be choosable between `resolverA` and `resolverB`.
If `resolverA` is selected the second parameter should allow `callA` and `callB`. If `callA` is selected the third parameter payload should expect type `DataA`. If `callB` is selected payload should expect type `DataB`.
If `resolverB` is selected the second parameter should only allow `resolve`. If selected payload should expect type `DataC`.

Comment: Like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/w225zw)?  Frankly I'm getting tired of seeing minor variations of this question cropping up and I don't think I've got enough stamina to write up an answer for it.  I'm going to disengage and maybe come back later if nobody else posts, but I think in any case I probably can't commit to continue for any future versions of this same thing.

Comment: Oop, I got to a pretty [similar conclusion](https://tsplay.dev/NB8J4W)

Comment: Sorry for tiring you.  Even more thank you then for solving my problem!  This is exactly what I was hoping for. Could you explain in detail how `resolverC` is excluded?

Comment: @pink could you explain the exact difference of your conclusion and why it works anyway? 

Comment: It does the exact same thing as jcalz's but achieves it in a different manner. The idea is the same; only the execution is different. To exclude `resolverC`, we check if the value of the property is an object, and if the values of that object contain a function. If it isn't an object, or if it doesn't contain a function, we exclude the key.